# nth-child equivalent in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

My problem is currently ONLY that the nth-child in css is acting very slow on google chrome.

So I want to write this code in an alternative option such as javascript/jquery or another language to do the exact same.

```
div.testbox:nth-child(4n+6) {
margin-left : 0px;
margin-right : 1%;
}
div.testbox:nth-child(4n+3) {
margin-left : 0px;
margin-right : 0px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure but https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ sounds like what you are looking for?

Comment: Most probably the issue is something else

Comment: I'd be surprised if jQuery's implementation was indeed faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery equivalent,

Example:

Select each `<p>` element that is the third child of its parent:

```
$("p:nth-child(3)")
```

Syntax:

```
:nth-child(n|even|odd|formula)
```

OR Use eq();

Select the second `<p>` element:

```
$("p:eq(1)")
```

Syantax:

```
$(":eq(index)")
```

I would use jQuery it's almost exactly the same syntax as CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically the same syntax. I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m53zq55y/) to show the results.

```
$("div.testbox:nth-child(4n+6)").css('background-color', "#333");
$("div.testbox:nth-child(4n+3)").css('background-color', "#eee");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure JavaScript version of @Victory's answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/c7m16z5h/

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.testbox:nth-child(4n+6)")).map(function(i) {
    i.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
});
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.testbox:nth-child(4n+3)")).map(function(i) {
    i.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
});
```

```css
div.testbox:nth-child(4n+6) {
    color: red;
}
div.testbox:nth-child(4n+3) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
<div class="testbox">here is some text</div>
```

Even better though, make it a function if you are going to use it over and over:

```
(function (win) {
    win.styleChange = function (selectors, styleProp, styleValue) {
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).map(function (i) {
            i.style[styleProp] = styleValue;
        });
    };
}(window));
styleChange("div.testbox:nth-child(4n+6)", "backgroundColor", "#333");
styleChange("div.testbox:nth-child(4n+3)", "backgroundColor", "#eee");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/pL7Ln3dz/